# Get from EntityFramework repository and change value has been same value

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In my code if i get object (for example user object) from EntityFramework repository :

```
  User GetUser(string name)
  {
     return user =  _repo.Get<User>(user=>user.name=name);
  }

  void Main()
  {

    var user0 = GetUser("foo");//user.pass==245 in Database

    user0.pass=345; //Change user.pass in user0 variable

    var user1=GetUser("foo");//user.pass==345 in Database !!!!!
  }
```

Why  in line -3-  of main method when i want get user from database again, user1.pass == `345`  but realy in Database is `245` ???

Comment: do you have a save method in your repo?

Comment: @Pedro yes i have save method!

Comment: Because you already have materialized the `User` and the object `user1` is same as `user0`. Check the result of `user0 == user1`.

Comment: Your GetUser method won't compile as is. Please post the real code.

Comment: @demoncodemonkey I'm pretty sure it compiles, so it could be the real code..

Comment: @PeterHansen How can it compile like that? Unless `user` (in `return user`) is a member variable -- but then wouldn't it conflict with the lambda `user` ?

Comment: @demoncodemonkey I was thinking he had a member variable called user, yes. But you're right, it would conflict with the parameter in the lambda. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're changing the user0 object, you're actually changing the EF representation of the database. Any changes you make will sit in EF until you call SaveChanges whereupon it will save the changes to the database.

If you call Get on your repo after you have made a change, EF framework will recognise that you have already called Get for the same Entity and will return you its copy of the foo user rather than making a trip to the database.

To avoid EF from caching an object you're bringing back you can use the `.AsNoTracking` method the first time you want to return the foo user. This will either be applied to the `_repo.Get<User>(user=>user.name=name)` line or possibly within the implementation of the `Get` method depending on what _repo is and what `Get` returns.

Comment: What should I do to fix this problem

Comment: @nocamer - I have edited my answer to include a potential step to avoid caching